# Is there a VB.NET equivalent of the UpDown VB6 control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, vb6, vb6-migration

Is there a VB.NET equivalent of the UpDown VB6 control? I'm remaking a VB6 user control as a .net winform.

Comment: Very hard to miss the NumericUpDown control in the toolbox.  Look around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

> Represents a Windows spin box (also known as an up-down control) that displays numeric values.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20up%20down%20control) was my Google Search.